# Copy array instead of simply assigning a reference on mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

This is about Automapper 9.
Let's say you have two classes like

```
public class Entity {
  public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; 
}
public class Model {
  public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; 
}
// mapping
CrateMap<Entity, Model>().ReverseMap();
```

When mapping, AutoMapper would simply copy array's reference to target. Which works for me, but only when projection is in direction from Entity to Model. When mapping Model back to Entity, I'd like to copy the array by value instead.
Using a [type converter](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html) won't work since it has collateral effects as it is a global converter. A [value converter](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Value-converters.html) won't work either, since you can't access the target property, but just return a (new) instance of byte array.
Ideally I would use a type converter on a CreateMap (without ReverseMap) but I doubt that's possible.

So I'm a bit stuck on how to do it properly.

Comment: To get the terminilogy right, you do not want a copy/shallow clone, but a deep clone. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloning_(programming)

Comment: Well, no. I don't want a clone in first place. I want array to be copied by value and not by reference.

Comment: That is what we call a **deep clone/copy**.

Comment: I have a target instance with an existing array, I have a source instance with an existing array. I want the values from source array to be copied into target instance instead. I consider clone to be a new instance with values copied, not a simple array copy operation. I could be wrong, but can we concentrate on solution instead.

Comment: Also note that source and target types are different.

Comment: Perhaps the projection in the caption was wrong, I meant mapping, not projection. Nevertheless this isn't cloning.

Comment: The source and target types are different, but at some point some field (RowVersion) have exactly the same type (byte[]). And for this field, you want a cloning of values.

Comment: You could specify mapping for RowVersion manually (auto-mapper allows this)   and create new instance of  RowVersion in this case instead getting link

Comment: I wish to preserve original target's byte[] instance though (and copy new values into it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you expect, I think you could use `AfterMap` to access both the source object and the destination object

```
this.CreateMap<Entity, Model>()
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForMember(destEntity => destEntity.RowVersion, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .AfterMap((srcModel, destEntity) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < srcModel.RowVersion.Length; i++)
        {
            destEntity.RowVersion[i] = srcModel.RowVersion[i];
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, but that most probably won't work either. Because mapping operation would already assign a new reference and AfterMap would work on this new reference instead on original one.

Comment: However, it's a good start. If I disable mapping of RowVersion first, and use your AfterMap it might just work.

Comment: Does it disable only in direction from Model->Entity?

Comment: Yes because `.AfterMap` is placed after the `.ReverseMap`

Comment: The only better solution would be if I could use a type converter. Thanks.